# groupNoAdjacency Recursion Problem in Core Java Programming

Tags: java, recursion

I have the below question as well as this time i have done some R&D and arrived at the solution but there is a glitch in the solution (one scenario)as well.

Q: groupNoAdjacent recursion problem :: Given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of the ints, such that the group sums to the given target with this additional constraint: If a value in the array is chosen to be in the group, the value immediately following it in the array must not be chosen. (No loops needed.)

```
groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 12) => true --> This is true coz of 2+10 =12,NoAdjacency    
groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 14) => false -> 10+4=14,numbers are adjacent,its false    
groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 7) => false  --> 2+5=7,numbers are adjacent,its false
```

my solution is as below.It works for all the below given scenarios except for one scenario.

---

### Code:

```
public boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] numbers, int target) {    
       start=0;    
       boolean[] reached = new boolean[target+1];         
       reached[0] = true;            
          for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){    
               for (int j = i + 2; j<numbers.length; j++){    
                  if(numbers[j] + numbers[i] == target){      
                      reached[target]=true;          
                  }else if(numbers[j] + numbers[i] < target){    
                      numbers[i] = numbers[j] + numbers[i];    
                  }     
            }          
       }            
      return reached[target];      
 }
```

Scenarios are given below

```
                          Expected This Run   
groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 12) → true true OK      
groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 14) → false false OK      
groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 7) → false false OK      
groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4, 2}, 7) → true true OK      
groupNoAdj(0, {2, 5, 10, 4}, 9) → true true OK      
groupNoAdj(0, {10, 2, 2, 3, 3}, 15) → true true OK      
groupNoAdj(0, {10, 2, 2, 3, 3}, 7) → false false OK      
groupNoAdj(0, {}, 0) → true true OK      
**groupNoAdj(0, {1}, 1) → true false X**      
groupNoAdj(0, {9}, 1) → false false OK      
groupNoAdj(0, {9}, 0) → true true OK      
groupNoAdj(0, {5, 10, 4, 1}, 11) → true true OK
```

My Code is not working for the one marked in BOLD.any ideas or inputs or suggestions you would like to give.i have tried analysing the code but since i did not get the solution for an exceptional scenario im posting it in Stackoverflow.

Comment: The problem statement mentions recursion and says "no loops needed". Your solution has loops and does not use recursion. If this is an assignment (and it smells like one) your answer seems not what they are looking for.

Comment: @Paul,Im first trying my hand without recursion.This not a homework problem,i just got the problem from one of the interviews which i faced earlier.i want to practise without recursion,understand the logic and then perhaps build one on recursion

Comment: OK. The recursive one is a lot easier :)

Comment: @Paul,if you could post the solution of recursive call,it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of this line:

i is starting at 0, j initializes to 0+2=2, but numbers.length is 1, so the code inside the loop never executes.

```
       for (int j = i + 2; j<numbers.length; j++){
```

because of this line, i is starting at 0, j initializes to 0+2=2, but numbers.length is 1, so the code inside the loop never executes.

Since you're wasting a lot of space with an array of booleans, you can simply explicitly look for short arrays.

```
if (numbers.length<1 && target==0){return true;)
```

at the beginning.  Then, as you iterate through the list while your target, this will work (I think).  As long as you are ok returning true for (0, {1,2}1), which based upon your test cases looks to be acceptable.

```
for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
     for (int j=2;j<numbers.length;j++){
          if (target-numbers[i]-numbers[j]==0){return true;}
     }
     if (target-numbers[i]==0){ return true;}
     curr+=target[i];
}
return false;
```

Comment: what is the fix required if i dont have to do an explict set of `reached[0] = true;`

Comment: Firstly, it wouldn't work if you searched groupNoAdj(0, {4}, 0).  I'm not sure what the fix would be.  You might want to check the size of the list first and deal with small arrays first.  I'll think about it and edit.  You're also using up a lot of memory by making a large array when you do boolean[] reached = new boolean[target+1];

Comment: groupNoAdj(0, {1}, 1) → true false X returns FALSE ,what modifications i have to do for original source code

Answer (score 4):

```
public boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
   if (target == 0)
   return true;
   if (start < nums.length)
   return groupNoAdj(start + 2,nums,target - nums[start]) || groupNoAdj(start + 1,nums,target);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is my recursive solution.

```
public boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] nums, int target)
{
    if (start >= nums.length)
    {
        return target == 0;
    }  

    if (groupNoAdj(start+1, nums, target - nums[start])
     && groupNoAdj(start+2, nums, target - nums[start]))
    {
        return true; 
    }

    if (groupNoAdj(start+1, nums, target))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive version with no loops (in Scala, not Java, though).

```
val cases = List(
(0, List(2, 5, 10, 4), 12),      
(0, List(2, 5, 10, 4), 14),     
(0, List(2, 5, 10, 4), 7),
(0, List(2, 5, 10, 4, 2), 7),
(0, List(2, 5, 10, 4), 9),
(0, List(10, 2, 2, 3, 3), 15),
(0, List(10, 2, 2, 3, 3), 7),
(0, List[Int](), 0),
(0, List(1), 1), 
(0, List(9), 1),
(0, List(9), 0),
(0, List(5, 10, 4, 1), 11))

for ((_,l, total) <- cases)
    println(l.mkString("(", ",",")") + " " + makeTotal(l, total))


def makeTotal(l:List[Int], total:Int):Boolean = {
if (l.isEmpty)
    total == 0 
else
    makeTotal(l.drop(1),total) || makeTotal(l.drop(2), total - l.head)
}
```

Explanation:

- If we've got an empty list (no more numbers) then it succeeds only if the total is zero.
- otherwise, if we don't select this element, we need to make `total` from the rest of the list
- if we do select this element, `total` is reduced by the value of this element, and we need to make that new total from the rest of the list, excluding the next element
- if either of those two succeed, we have a success.

Comment: Thanks biut in case you have in java it would be helpful.

Comment: I don't really do Java :( The only think I think you need to know is that drop(n) returns a list with the first n elements removed, and 'head' returns the first element of a list. The first for/println is just printing the result - makeTotal is all you need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a short recursive solution, this is mine:

```
public boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  
  if(target == 0) return true;
  
  if(target < 0 || start >= nums.length) return false;
  
  
  return groupNoAdj(start + 1, nums, target)
      || groupNoAdj(start + 2, nums, target - nums[start]);
  
  
}
```